# Element type error on a firebase-React Native project

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

Im new at coding and am making a firebase-react native app. What I want to do know is the app to show users the login screen if they are not login yet and show the app screen if they are log in but when I try to run the app, it gives me the error shown in the image below. What Im doing wrong? Thank you.

```
/**
 * @format
 */
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Navigator
} from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import App from './component/App'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import Login from './component/Login'
//import Firebase from './lib/Firebase'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "dhshdsjkfbsdjkvbjksdvbjksd",
    authDomain: "dhshdsjkfbsdjkvbjksdvbjksd",
    databaseURL: "dhshdsjkfbsdjkvbjksdvbjksd",
    projectId: "dhshdsjkfbsdjkvbjksdvbjksd",
    storageBucket: "dhshdsjkfbsdjkvbjksdvbjksd",
    messagingSenderId: "dhshdsjkfbsdjkvbjksdvbjksd",
    appId: "dhshdsjkfbsdjkvbjksdvbjksd",
    measurementId: "dhshdsjkfbsdjkvbjksdvbjksd"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default class dribbleAppUi1 extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            initialView : null,
            userLoaded: false
        }
        this.getInitialView()
        this.getInitialView = this.getInitialView.bind(this)
    }

    getInitialView (){
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            let initialView = user ? 'App' : 'Login'

            this.setState({
                userLoaded: true,
                initialView
            })
        })  
    }

    configureScene(route) {
        if(route.sceneConfig) {
            return route.sceneConfig
        } else {
            return ({
                ...Navigator.sceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJumpFromRight,
                gestures: {}
            })
        }
    }

    
    renderScene(route, navigator){
        var globalProps = {navigator}
        switch(route.id){
            case 'App':
                return (
                    <App navigator={navigator} />
                )
                case 'Login':
                    return (
                        <Login navigator={navigator} />
                    )
        }
    }
    render() {
        if(this.state.userLoaded) {

            return (
                <Navigator
                  initialRoute={{
                      id: this.state.initialView
                  }}
                  renderScene={this.renderScene}
                  configureScene={this.configureScene}
                  />
            );

        }else {
            return null
        }
       
    }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('Tiismo', () => dribbleAppUi1);
```

[image]Im trying to make a project with firebase and react native. For now, Im trying to get users to login page if there are no login but I'm getting the error in the image below. What Im doing wrong? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply return null in render. Try this.

```
 if(this.state.userLoaded) {

        return (
            <Navigator
              initialRoute={{
                  id: this.state.initialView
              }}
              renderScene={this.renderScene}
              configureScene={this.configureScene}
              />
        );

    }else {
        return (<Text>Loading</Text>)
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help but it is giving me the same error. What else can I do?

Comment: Well another issue is with you class name. It should start with a capital letter. Try naming your class DribbleAppUi1.